# Web service failing with The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, iis-7, .net-4.0

I have a very long running task I need to take from my website and put into a web service however every time I try call the web service I get this error message `The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.`

I assumed this could just be an issue with the credentials as I have seen something similar when sending emails so I did this:

```
      Dim wsCustomer As New blueprintdev.RosterEmailService()

      Dim basicAuthenticationInfo As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass")

      wsCustomer.UseDefaultCredentials = False

      wsCustomer.PreAuthenticate = True

      wsCustomer.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo

      txtTestResult.Text = wsCustomer.Test()
```

This still gives me the same issue.

Also tried this using default credentials and that still does not help.

Now I have no idea how to properly do this, and so I have mostly worked off tutorials etc, can anyone tell me what im doing wrong here?

Thanks

Additional notes: the project im working on is one I inherited when I joined the company and cant be built in visual studio so breakpointing through the code is not an option for me without massively hacking the project and removing a lot of code.

Update: Running fiddler shows me 3 entries, when I look at the auth tab i see:

```
No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present.

WWW-Authenticate Header (Negotiate) appears to be a Kerberos reply:
A1 15 30 13 A0 03 0A 01 03 A1 0C 06 0A 2B 06 01  ¡.0. ....¡...+..
04 01 82 37 02 02 0A                             ..7...
```

Then

```
No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present.

WWW-Authenticate Header (Negotiate) appears to be a Kerberos reply:
A1 81 E2 30 81 DF A0 03 0A 01 01 A2 81 D7 04 81  ¡â0ß ....¢×.
D4 4E 54 4C 4D 53 53 50 00 02 00 00 00 0E 00 0E  ÔNTLMSSP........
00 38 00 00 00 15 82 89 E2 C1 20 C3 44 5E 99 21  .8....âÁ ÃD^!
A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 8E 00 8E 00 46 00 00   ..........F..
00 06 01 B1 1D 00 00 00 0F 41 00 43 00 41 00 44  ...±.....A.C.A.D
00 45 00 4D 00 59 00 02 00 0E 00 41 00 43 00 41  .E.M.Y.....A.C.A
00 44 00 45 00 4D 00 59 00 01 00 06 00 44 00 45  .D.E.M.Y.....D.E
00 56 00 04 00 1A 00 6C 00 6F 00 63 00 61 00 6C  .V.....l.o.c.a.l
00 2E 00 41 00 63 00 61 00 64 00 65 00 6D 00 79  ...A.c.a.d.e.m.y
00 03 00 22 00 44 00 45 00 56 00 2E 00 6C 00 6F  ...".D.E.V...l.o
00 63 00 61 00 6C 00 2E 00 41 00 63 00 61 00 64  .c.a.l...A.c.a.d
00 65 00 6D 00 79 00 05 00 1A 00 6C 00 6F 00 63  .e.m.y.....l.o.c
00 61 00 6C 00 2E 00 41 00 63 00 61 00 64 00 65  .a.l...A.c.a.d.e
00 6D 00 79 00 07 00 08 00 2E 76 48 74 53 21 CD  .m.y......vHtS!Í
01 00 00 00 00        

                       .....
```

And finally this one highlighted in red

```
No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present.

No WWW-Authenticate Header is present.
```

Does this mean the authentication data is being lost somewhere between client and server? or that I am not passing anything to begin with?

Comment: The first step to finding the source of the problem is to connect to the web service yourself through a browser- if you get a 401 too then you need to talk to whoever provides the web service and ask them to let you through. If not then you know it is about your application credentials. A tool like Fiddler can show you what HTTP traffic is going past and will often help reveal where problems are coming from in this type of situation.

Comment: Thanks, I can connect to the service via the browser and just get a basic overview screen listing the methods. Where abouts should I look in fiddler?

Comment: Add this to web.config :<system.net>     <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false">       <proxy usesystemdefault="true"/>     </defaultProxy>   </system.net>

Comment: @Lily Still getting the 401 error :(

Comment: If you run Fiddler on the machine making the calls you should be able to pick up the HTTP Traffic between it and the Web Service server, assuming they are on different machines. That will show you what credentials it is actually trying to use and what response the server is returning.

Comment: @glenatron I've added what I see in fiddler to my question. Does this mean my authentication details are being lost somewhere on the way to the server?

Comment: It sounds like when it's making the web service calls it's not actually using the authentication stuff. You should be able ( I don't have Fiddler in front of me so I can't tell you where ) to see the actual XML and headers of your request in a text literal rather than with all the hex data, that makes them a bit easier to read. It's one of the panels on the right, but I don't remember which one.

Comment: @glenatron There is a an XML tab but it's always empty

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the service through a browser I suggest passing in your username including domain as the credentials.

The username would look something like this: DOMAIN\USER

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and the username and password had to be explicitly added.

ie.

```
   wsCustomer.username = "something"
   wsCustomer.password = "something else"
```

I guess you're already doing that with:

```
 Dim basicAuthenticationInfo As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
```

but maybe worth a try